# (Swift) How to pass data back and forth between UITableView and UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm a beginning iOS developer and I've been stuck on an issue for quite some time now.

**Background:**
I have a single viewcontroller in which I have placed a TableView (I cannot use a tableviewcontroller). It holds 4 dynamic prototype cells:
Cell 1 has an UITextField and a couple of labels, Cell 2-4 only have a label (with different types of information) and have to be hidden initially.

When an user enters a number (max. 3 digits) in the UITextField of the first cell, the number has to be compared to check if it is a correct/existing number. If this number proves correct, 2 things will have to happen: 1) the labels in the first cell will need to change layout (colour, font, size, ...) and set the data of one label. 2) the other cells in the tableview will have to appear beneath the first cell.

**Problem:** 
I'm having trouble sending data back and forth between the first UITableViewCell and its UITableView. For the text input I use the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method in the cell class, which then limits the # of digits and calls a method in the tableView class where the data will be compared. For this I used delegation.

However, after checking whether the number is a match, I need to call a method in the cell class (from within the tableview class) that will change the layout and set the data of a label in the cell. Yet I can't seem to figure out a way to make this method call work and access the outlets.

**Summarised:** cell class sends number to tableview class, methods in tableview class run, tableview class sends bool to cell class where outlets need to be changed.

**What I tried:** 
I tried setting up delegation in the other direction, but it wouldn't trigger. Using a normal method call wouldn't work either, because then the outlets are nil.

I believe my problem lies in the fact that I need to reference the same instance/object of the cell to access the outlets?

I selected and simplified the relevant pieces of code:

**1) TableView class**

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, updateUITableView {

var existingNumber = 200
var cellsRowHeight = false

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

//Started by InputTableViewCell when UITextField has a 3 digit-number
func checkNumberInput(inputNumber: Int) {
    //Step 1: check if the number matches an existing one
    let match = checkNumberMatch(inputNumber: inputNumber)

    //Step 2: send a bool back to the cell class to change the layout through outlets
    InputTableViewCell().changeLayout(numberMatch: match) // <--- problem

    //Step 3: make the hidden cells appear
    toggleCellsVisibility(numberMatch: match)
}

//Step 1
func checkNumberMatch(inputNumber: Int) -> Bool {
    if inputNumber == existingNumber {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

//Step 2
func toggleCellsVisibility(numberMatch: Bool) {
    cellsRowHeight = numberMatch
    if numberMatch == true { //cells appear
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        //possible additional code
    } else { //cells dissappear
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        //possible additional code
    }
}

//Step 3
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0 where !cellsRowHeight || cellsRowHeight:
        return 170
    case 1 where !cellsRowHeight:
        return 0
    case 1 where cellsRowHeight:
        return 54
    //cases for other cells to appear/dissappear
    default:
        return 44
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //Create tableViewCell
        let cellIdentifier = "InputCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! InputTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        //Customize lay-out of cell
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

        return cell
    }
    //creation of other cells
}

// MARK: - Loading
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
}}
```

**2) Cell class:**

```
protocol updateUITableView: class {
func checkNumberInput(inputNumber: Int)
}

class InputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
var delegate: updateUITableView?

@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var letterLabel: UILabel!

//Step 2: problem!
func changeLayout(numberMatch: Bool) {
    if numberMatch == true {
        print("Success") //this line triggers
        letterLabel?.text = "A" //is nil
        //other lay-out changes
    }
    else {
        print("Fail, please provide an existing number")
        //other lay-out changes
    }
}

//Set maximum character limit in textField and dismiss keyboard when character limit is reached.
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length

    if (newLength == 3) {
        textField.text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        //Get text from textField
        let numberInput: Int? = Int(textField.text!)
        if numberInput != nil {
            delegate?.checkNumberInput(number: numberInput!) //send number to tableview class
        }
        //Dismiss keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}

func viewDidLoad() {
}}
```

The actual problem is situated in "Step 2". Using this method I can perform the print statement, but the actual labels/outlets are nil because it is just a generic call.

Any help would be immensely appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your UITableViewCell instance in your delegate method like this

```
func checkNumberInput(senderCell: InputTableViewCell,inputNumber: Int)
```

and then you will be able to call any method on this cell's instance. So in your case.

```
func checkNumberInput(senderCell: InputTableViewCell,inputNumber: Int){
//...
   senderCell.changeLayout(numberMatch: match) 
//....
}
```

and you can call your method like

```
delegate?.checkNumberInput(senderCell: self, inputNumber: numberInput!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass data using NSNotificationCenter.

Put this code in viewDidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedDataFromNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "receiveData"), object: nil)
```

This selector method for notification

```
func receivedDataFromNotification(notification : NSNotification) -> Void {}
```

Then Post Notification while you need to pass data.

```
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "receiveData"), object: YourObject)
```